# Cloudinary: How do I upload images to cloudinary in Android in Signed manner

Tags: android, cloudinary

I am trying to upload images to cloudinary from android and I am facing a lot of issues. I initialised the MediaManager like this in my onCreate method:

```
Map config = new HashMap();
        config.put("cloud_name", "");
        config.put("use_filename", true);
        MediaManager.init(this, config);
```

and I am calling the upload method:

```
MediaManager.get().upload(filePath).dispach();
```

but it gives me the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must supply api_key
```

even when I am providing my api key and my cloudinary url under meta-data in my manifest file. I went though the git link for the image upload part and I am following exactly like it said.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, looks like you are using an old version of Cloudinary Android SDK.

Maybe you should try using the [new one](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_android).

Regarding the deletion issue:

It's true that deletion must be done only via [authenticated API](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#deleting_images) (from your server) or with delete token.
In order to receive a deletion token in the upload response, add the `return_delete_token` parameter to the upload method and set it to `true`.
Now you can use this code to delete the image:

`MediaManager.get().getCloudinary().uploader().deleteByToken(token);`

Note that the token is limited to 10 minutes.

Comment: the example linked is great but I did not find a way to upload the images to a particular folder in cloudinary. How do I do that?

Comment: You can do that with the `folder` option, like that:


`MediaManager.get().getCloudinary().uploader().option("folder","folder_name").deleteByToken(token);`

Comment: I am not trying to delete the images as of now, earlier I was uploading the images in unsigned manner, which is quite easy, but now I have changed my code and am trying to upload the images in signed manner as explained here: https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_android/tree/master/sample-signed. But I am not quite able to make this work

Comment: I get the error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must supply api_key, so, I supply the api_key like this: config.put("api_key", "my_api_key")

Comment: My question is If I am trying to make a signed upload then why does the app keep asking for my credentials.

Comment: HI Bijoy. 
Yes, I'm sorry about the delete issue, the code to upload an image to a specific folder is like that:
`MediaManager.get().getCloudinary().uploader().option("folder","folder_name")`